# kubernetes elastic all-in-one fails on arm64 machines?

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, kubernetes, elastic-stack

I was working on setting up ELK on a Kubernetes cluster, and it works on my macbookpro for tests, but when i tried to do it on my ubunutu arm64 machines clustered together it fails.

When i noticed it was giving exec errors, I immediately knew it was failing to run an arm64 variant as I had a similar issue with some containers i was using for different projects and just needed to use buildx to create arm64 support.

Anyways, This is my current flow.  Join me on an adventure.

Given a fresh Ubuntu install on a Arm64, Raspberry Pi 4, 4G.

1. Update, Upgrade, and install kubeadm,kubectl, etc.  I set up a second machine, so now i have a cluster of size 2.  (sweet! Im proud so far!)
2. I go to the k8s website, and grab the all in one.
   `kubectl apply -f https://download.elastic.co/downloads/eck/1.3.0/all-in-one.yaml`
3. Now that all the kubernetes is set up, I should be able to launch my Elasticsearch pod, and I do.  I do a kubectl get elasticsearch to see my new pod.  Says the name but no state.
4. Time to see whats up.  `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces`

BUT WAIT. What is this, elastic-operator-0.  Interesting, never used THIS before.  BUT it exists on my machine and on my pro, so it much have some value.  Wait. Its in an indefinite crashloopbackoff.  Interesting.  Attempts to describe or logs failed.  Realized it is giving exec errors, which I know is from an architecture mismatch.

So this leads me to now.

Desired Endstate:

I am trying to install Elasticsearch, Kibana, and Logstash.
Elasticsearch AND Kibana arent built off of images, but instead the Types in the all in one,   elasticseatch.k8s.elastic.co and kibana.k8s.elastic.co respectively.  Logstash though is built off of a docker container: docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:7.9.2

So here is my conundrum.   How do I get this back up and functional?  It seems that kibana and elasticsearch are not developing state (red, green or otherwise) until this elastic-operator-0 is up and running.

I am trying to trim and clean this all up such this works again.  I have no problem with removing everything installed with all-in-one, and then just doing tweaks but im not sure how much additional work it would be.

Below is my sample YAML file.

```
---
apiVersion: elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/v1
kind: Elasticsearch
metadata:
  name: elasticsearch
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: eck-logstash
    app.kubernets.io/component: elasticsearch
spec:
  version: 7.9.2
  nodeSets:
    - name: default
      count: 1
      config:
        node.store.allow_mmap: false
---
apiVersion: kibana.k8s.elastic.co/v1
kind: Kibana
metadata:
  name: kibana
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: eck-logstash
    app.kubernets.io/component: kibana
spec:
  version: 7.9.2
  count: 1
  elasticsearchRef:
    name: elasticsearch
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap

metadata:
  name: logstash-config
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: eck-logstash
    app.kubernets.io/component: logstash
data:
  logstash.yml: |
    http.host: "0.0.0.0"
    path.config: /usr/share/logstash/pipeline
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: logstash-pipeline
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: eck-logstash
    app.kubernets.io/component: logstash
data:
  logstash.conf: |
    input { }

    filter { }

    output {
      elasticsearch {
        hosts => [ "${ES_HOSTS}" ]
        user => "${ES_USER}"
        password => "${ES_PASSWORD}"
        cacert => '/etc/logstash/certificates/ca.crt'
        index => "sample-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
      }
    }
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: logstash
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: eck-logstash
    app.kubernets.io/component: logstash
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: eck-logstash
      app.kubernets.io/component: logstash
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: eck-logstash
        app.kubernets.io/component: logstash
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: logstash
          image: docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:7.9.2
          env:
            - name: ES_HOSTS
              value: "https://elasticsearch-es-http.default.svc:9200"
            - name: ES_USER
              value: "elastic"
            - name: CUSTOM_ENV_TEST
              value: "Helloworld"
            - name: ES_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: elasticsearch-es-elastic-user
                  key: elastic
          volumeMounts:
            - name: config-volume
              mountPath: /usr/share/logstash/config
            - name: pipeline-volume
              mountPath: /usr/share/logstash/pipeline
            - name: ca-certs
              mountPath: /etc/logstash/certificates
              readOnly: true
      volumes:
        - name: config-volume
          configMap:
            name: logstash-config
        - name: pipeline-volume
          configMap:
            name: logstash-pipeline
        - name: ca-certs
          secret:
            secretName: elasticsearch-es-http-certs-public
```

Comment: To clarify, you have tested this on you mac and later you want to deploy it on Raspberry Pi with Ubuntu using the same configuration?

Comment: Correct, It runs on multiple Pros, but when running it on a Pi64 Ubunutu machine, it fails at the "elastic-operator" level, which is the item i presume is preventing the other items to load

Comment: @PjoterS I am trying to think if there are other constraints I could think of, I have 2 additional docker containers running outside of k8s, and one had an image problem with exec ( So i needed to find arm64 compatible images in the image history and adjust accordingly ) which is how i knew it was some sort of image issue within kubernetes.